# "Remaining to wear" : odd choice of expression by the Daily Mail Online

Tags: passive-voice, headlinese, error

From the *[Daily Mail Online](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3808514/Strictly-unfazed-Zoe-Ball-high-spirits-returns-TV-time-announcing-Norman-Cook-split-wearing-wedding-ring.html)*

> The presenter, 45, was in high spirits as she took charge of Strictly Come Dancing spin-off *It Takes Two* - and baffled viewers **by remaining to wear her wedding ring.**

The writing on the Mail Online can be pretty baffling at the best of times, and I think this short excerpt is proof of that. It is common for English speaking journalists to take shortcuts by omitting prepositions, articles, pronouns etc., and preferring punchier words to convey a sense of urgency, and lend their articles a more dramatic tone.

However, the  last line written in the passive voice, especially bothers me. I understand what it means: the female presenter who recently split (separated) from her husband, wore her wedding ring on the show, but how does someone "***remain*** to wear a wedding ring"?

1. Is this an error? Is it slang? Does it sound OK to native speakers?
2. What should the author have written? I would have said:

> ... **by keeping her wedding ring on**.

Although *keeping to wear her wedding ring*, sounds even worse than the original phrase.

3. What rule of grammar is this sentence construction breaking? If any?
4. Is this an example of contemporary English?

Comment: deciding to wear...  would be the least disruptive change. I've never heard "remaining to wear".  I might be among the easily baffled.

Comment: @TRomano but doesn't  *'deciding to wear'* suggest she had taken her wedding ring off at some point in the past? She then made a conscious decision to wear it again.

Comment: No.  I decide to wear my pajamas to work. I already have them on.

Comment: @TRomano but you don't always wear pyjamas, (unlike a wedding ring) and it wouldn't mean you normally wear pajamas to work.

Comment: Deciding to wear...doesn't imply that she put the ring on, only that she kept the ring on.  The decision was to wear or not to wear, and it could be made even if the ring was on her finger at the time of the decision.  You could say "by deciding to keep wearing" if you wanted to make it perfectly clear.  You can **decide to remain clothed** when you step in the shower, if you don't care about soggy shoes.

Comment: @TRomano I suppose you can make a decision to either keep wearing a ring or to take it off, but it is "remain" and "keep" that hints at continuation. Your "by deciding to keep wearing her wedding ring" is a bit awkward sounding :)

Comment: That **remain** and **keep** indicate continuation does not mean that in their absence the meaning must be otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, *continuing to wear* works. In the sentence, *remaining* 'sticks' closer to "the presenter"/"she" than her ring, or even her wearing her ring. I think this is the source of the weirdness. The technical terminology probably says something about *remaining* not being transitive, but I'm no linguist :) . I think typical constructions go along the lines "(three days remaining) to (wear ...)", rather than "... (remaining to wear) ...". As for your Q4, if it's contemporary English, it's unfamiliar to me. There is an idiomatic phrase "it remains to be seen", though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What, you want me to formalise that load of ... musings? :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're welcome. I've posted my musings on this. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. Is this an error? Is it slang? Does it sound OK to native speakers?

Let's remove the extraneous material from the sentence:

- The presenter baffled viewers by remaining to wear her wedding ring.

This is comprehensible, but it isn't idiomatic unless the reporter was trying to say that the presenter remained on stage after the performance in order to wear (put on) her wedding ring.

> 2. What should the author have written?

The word *continuing* conveys the notion that conveys the sense you describe:

> **continue** *verb*
>   1.2 Remain in a specified position or state.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/continue)

- The presenter baffled viewers by continuing to wear her wedding ring.

> 3. What rule of grammar is this construction breaking? If any?

Consider the example given in the following definition:

> **Remain** *verb*
>   1.2 [with complement] Continue to possess a particular quality or fulfil a particular role.
>   *‘he had remained alert the whole time’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remain)

It is conceivable that the reporter was thinking of this usage. The following might be acceptable:

- Even after all that, she remained wearing her wedding ring.

It has a nostalgic sense as something about a woman who has been left behind but still holds the symbol of marriage dear.

However, your quote doesn't appear to have this connotation, leading to the *remained-on-stage* reading vying with the nostalgic sense. The result, strangely, sounds odd but still makes sense.

> 4. Is this an example of contemporary English?

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remaining%20to%20wear&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) doesn't appear to have any instances of "remaining to wear", but it only reports up to 2008, so there may be more recent instances that remain unreported.

Looking at the first page returned by a google search for "remaining to wear" (with quotes), we get several examples like the following, which is a different construction to your quote:

- Hopefully after you have decluttered you will have enough clothing remaining to wear and there will be no need to add to this for some time.
  [- itmakescents](http://www.itmakescents.net/dress-like-minimalist)

Only one of the examples fits the construction of your quote; it is dated May 28 2014, so can be considered contemporary:

- Ghost skills allow you to obtain low detection while remaining to wear heavier armors or weapons and still be able to participate in stealth aspects of the heist.
  [- STEAM](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=262139982)

As noted by @StarWeaver and @TRomano in comments, this site contains other instances of non-idiomatic usage. The STEAM quote cited is in English and it is contemporary, but it might be a stretch to call it *Contemporary English* as used by the wider community of native English speakers.

Note that your quote features on several of the links returned on the first page. One of them is a variant of the page you linked to. Its headline includes the following words, agreeing with my suggestion above to use *continuing* instead of *remaining*:

- Jovial Zoe continues to wear wedding ring
  [- Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3809480/Zoe-Ball-continues-wear-wedding-ring-steps-days-announcing-split-Norman-Cook.html)

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but there is no copyediting oversight on Steam community guides, and it's not uncommon to find some tortured english in some cases.

Comment: @StarWeaver Very relevant. Colloquial usage abounds on the internet, and every new turn of phrase must start somewhere. Nevertheless, "remaining to wear", in the *Daily Mail* sense, is one I hope doesn't become established. :)

Comment: The author of the STEAM piece uses many unidiomatic constructions. For example, "Viewers should also assume that I primarily focus on the viability in Very Hard or Overkill difficulties *and with less considerations to* other difficulty levels."

Comment: @TRomano I've edited to note my view on the STEAM usage - it's broadly in line with yours and StarWeaver's.

Comment: +1 One other note, if one wanted to use *remaining* with something being worn, the most idiomatic usage would be *remaining **in*** [the worn item]; for example, *Miss Havisham baffled wedding guests by **remaining in** her wedding gown after being jilted.* Even this construction sounds odd when combined with jewelry, however, as we don't typically say that someone is "in" a ring, necklace, etc. You might *almost* get to a natural construction with *baffled viewers by remaining **wearing** her wedding ring*, but that's still awkward-to-the-point-of-ugly.